# I deleted the apt folder from /var/cache inlcuding (I think) sources.list. What do I do now?

Tags: apt, installation, re-installation

I initially had a problem with apt-get update. It stopped on 99%, "waiting for headers". This problem came when attempting to install GeoGebra following instructions at [this](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3aheimdall78&package=geogebra) page.

Trying to solve this problem I deleted the apt folder from /var/cache. Now apt-get doesn't work at all. I have no idea of how to solve this problem. Ubuntu works fine but I'm unable to install new software. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/109970/debian-ubuntu-how-to-restore-var-cache-apt-structure-after-deleting-it) answer on ServerFault you need to do:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
sudo touch /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo chmod 640 /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.

However, apt-get update still does not work. I'm still stuck at 99% [Waiting for headers].

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1737697).